# Mat-select arrow to transform on dropdown (up and down)

Tags: javascript, css, angular, sass, angular8

I have a mat-select dropdown icon arrow that is faced down and when I click it transforms faced up and opens the dropdown options, and when I click on the arrow again, it closes the dropdown facing down again, so far so good, but when I select one of the options and it closes the dropdown with the option selected, the arrow doesn't face down again, unless I hold the click on the option.

I've been trying to use :focus for this transformation but I do not seem to figure out how to make it work properly.

I'm using this dropdown: https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview
(without the 'mat-form-field' in Angular 8)

My SCSS:

```
::ng-deep .mat-select-arrow {
  border-left: 15px solid transparent !important;
  border-right: none !important;
  border-top: 15px solid transparent !important;
  background-image: url(../../assets/icons/Icon_dropdown_Arrow_bottom.svg) !important;
  background-image: no-repeat !important;

  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.3s;
    -o-transition-duration: 0.3s;
    transition-duration: 0.3s;

    -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
    -moz-transition-property: -moz-transform;
    -o-transition-property: -o-transform;
    transition-property: transform;
}

:focus {
  &::ng-deep .mat-select-arrow {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
}
```

This code transforms the arrow icon that was down to up, but when I click to select the option, it doesn't get back to normal (down), unless I hold clicking. How to make it realize that when an option is selected it shouldn't be on focus anymore? Can't seem to figure out a proper transformation here. What am I missing?

I've been trying mat-select-option/mat-option to transform the arrow to 0 degree again when option selected but couldn't make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using `:checked` pseudo-class to revert it to normal? I presume you could try something similar to your ':focus':

```css
:checked {
  &::ng-deep .mat-select-arrow {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
}
```

You can check :checked pseudo-selector [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_checked.asp)